# Give user backup and restore privilege for delprof2?

Tags: permissions

We are trying to run delprof2 without having to right click and run as administrator. IWhen run on the technician account it says that the user doesnt have backup and restore privilege's.
Is it possible to assign these privliges to a user?

Mnay thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 user rights assignments that faciltate backing up and restoring files:

**Backup files and directories** and **Restore files and directories**

These user rights can be managed/granted in a few different ways:

1. Grant the appropriate user account both of these rights via Local Security Policy or via GPO.
2. Add the appropriate user to the Backup Operators group.

How to do this will depend on whether the server where the profiles exist is joined to a domain or not.

Comment: Thanks, The last one stopped the errors about backup rights.

Comment: Glad to help...